# Change value of a field in embed document with condition in mongo DB

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I try to get a data from the database. But I've had a problem in a section where I can't edit the value of the embedded fields. I want to put the **boolean** value instead of the mobile number.  if it has a value, equal to the `true` and if it does not have a value, it will be `false`.

I have document like this in my collection:

```
{
    "_id": ObjectId("606d6ea237c2544324925c61"),
    "title": "newwww",
    "message": [{
        "_id": ObjectId("606d6e1037c2544324925c5f"),
        "text": "aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa",
        "user_id": null,
        "user_full_name": null,
        "user_mobile_number": null,
        "submit_date": {
            "$date": "2021-04-07T08:32:16.093Z"
        }
    }, {
        "_id": ObjectId("606d6edc546feebf508d75f9"),
        "text": "aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa",
        "user_id": null,
        "user_full_name": null,
        "user_mobile_number": "9653256482",
        "submit_date": {
            "$date": "2021-04-07T08:35:40.881Z"
        }
    }],
    "user_mobile_number": "9652351489",
}
```

---

Do query:

```
db.ticket.aggregate([{"$match": {"_id": ObjectId("606d6ea237c2544324925c61")}}, {
        "$project": {"message.is_admin":{
                "$let": {
                    vars: {
                        mobile_number: "$message.user_mobile_numebr"
                    },
                    in: {
                        "$cond": [{$eq: ['$$mobile_number', null]},false,true ]
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }])
```

---

and result is:

```
[
  {
    "_id": ObjectId("606d6ea237c2544324925c61"),
    "message": [
      {
        "is_admin": true
      },
      {
        "is_admin": true
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

---

but i want result like this:

```
[
  {
    "_id": ObjectId("606d6ea237c2544324925c61"),
    "message": [
      {
        "is_admin": false
      },
      {
        "is_admin": true
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

means I want when message.user_mobile_number has value, get `true` and when value is null get `false`.

---

**How can I do this?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Demo - https://mongoplayground.net/p/h_zkRfDbZrS

Use [$map](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/map/)

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    "$project": {
      "message": {
        "$map": {
            input: "$message",
            "as": "message",
            "in": { 
                "$cond": [{ "$eq": [ "$$message.user_mobile_number", null ] }, { is_admin: false }, { is_admin: true } ]
            }
        }
      }
    }
  }
])
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Is it possible to have another field from message with is_admin?

Comment: @AmirhosseinAzhdari Which field do you want ?

Comment: For example, I want to get the `text` next to `is_admin`

Comment: @AmirhosseinAzhdari Yes check this https://mongoplayground.net/p/zhcc28_6q65

Comment: @AmirhosseinAzhdari Glad I could help, cheers :)